# Is it possible to add .css style to Jupyter notebook from separate file?

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I need to render some html tables in Jupyter Notebook and for this I have defined my own css styles. I want it to be reusable on any PC.

For now I need to run code like this in one of Jupyter cells:

```
%%html
<style>
.output_wrapper, .output {
    height:auto !important;
    max-height: none;
}
.output_scroll {
    box-shadow:none !important;
    webkit-box-shadow:none !important;
}

.package_header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0e2b59;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.placeholder {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 6px;
}

.passed_test_table {
  display: table;         
  width: 100%;         

  background-color: #ebffd3;                
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

# (...) rest of css classes omitted 
</style>
```

Yet I don't want to store this `style` inside Jupyter Notebook but in other file like my_default_style.css and load it somehow so it doesn't take too much space in Notebook making it less readable.

Is it possible to load .css style from some local file instead of running it in Jupyter Notebook cell directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are okay with the styling applying to all notebooks you make, then you can store your css in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` and this will be automatically loaded and will override any default styles.

An alternative is to do something like this:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import urllib2
HTML(urllib2.urlopen('[url to your css file here').read())
```

(from http://moderndata.plot.ly/custom-styling-for-ipython-notebooks-with-3-lines-of-code/)

Where you store your css file somewhere (e.g. on Github) and download it and apply it when you run the notebook.

If you want it to be completely external, use `custom.css`, but this will apply  to every notebook. If you need it to only apply to a single notebook, then you'll have to specify it within the notebook, but there are less verbose ways of doing it (like above).

See [configuration docs](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html#id1)

Comment: Thanks.
I figured it out in the past, but forgot to update here. I did it exactly that way.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Jupyter with Python 3 then there is no urllib2 (it was merged into urllib) and the answers above will give you the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'`. You may want something like this instead:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("[url to your css file here]")
HTML(html.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Note that `read()` returns a bytes encoding, which you must decode if you want text.

If you are using an inline CSS style, you can also pass it as part of the HTML content, for example in a `<style>` block. Here is a simple example:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
css_str = '<style>.foo{color:#F00;}</style>'
html_str = '<div class="foo">bar</div>'
html = HTML(css_str + html_str)
display(html)
```

Output is the word "bar" in red.

Comment: How do you apply this to the notebook? If I include this snippet of code in my notebook, it just pastes the linked CSS file.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos -- if I understand right, you want to pass a CSS string to display, rather than use a file? I've added an example of this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example! This wouldn't work in a Python code, though? What module (or something else) is the 'display' function from?

Comment: Re: "This wouldn't work in a Python code, though" -- I don't understand. This is an answer about Python 3 Jupyter notebooks. The module is IPython.display, which is built-it to Jupyter notebooks. Are you trying to run this code outside the Jupyter notebook interface, or not in a Python 3 Jupyter notebook? Otherwise, what version of Jupyter and what notebook type are you using?

Comment: Your code works in a Jupyter notebook, thank you very much! I'm just looking for a more seamless way to apply some CSS to a notebook, whithout having to change the content of the notebook itself.

Answer (score 4):

This answer would probably better be a comment on the earlier answer by Davies and Narasimhan, but I lack the reputation to post a comment.

`from IPython.core.display import HTML` will work, and was the recommended way to access HTML display capability in earlier versions of IPython.  But in recent versions, the *public* display API is in `IPython.display` (see its docstring). This module exposes `__all__` of `IPython.core.display`, along with `__all__` of `IPython.lib.display`.  Notably, the current IPython docs ([The IPython API](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html)) don't publicly document `IPython.core.display` separately.  For the current `IPython.display` docs, see: [Module: display — IPython documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#module-IPython.display).

So the recommended solution as of IPython 5 I believe would be:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import urllib2
HTML(urllib2.urlopen('[url to your css file here').read())
```